# Are there any tool to search / list of existing concept when developing ontology?

Tags: namespaces, semantic-web, ontology, vocabulary

Are there any search tool / list of common concept/vocabulary from existing schema that can be used as reference when developing new ontology?

e.g. foaf http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/

Currently I am developing new ontology, and wondering whether I need to create new concept or just use the existing one, such as abbreviation etc.

Comment: Check https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/

Comment: @StanislavKralin That's exactly what I need. Thanks